# Android subscriber can get msg but "rostopic echo" cannot?

Tags: android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, everyone. I am new to ROS Android and I'm playing with android_tutorial_pubsub. I run the program on AVD and run roscore on Ubuntu Desktop. As we know, the program on AVD creates a publisher as well as a subscriber, both on topic /chatter. The publisher publishes message "Helloworld n" per second and the subscriber recieves messages and show in TextView.
On my AVD,the TextView shows "Helloworld n" correctly. And on my Ubuntu Desktop, when I excute rostopic list, I can see a topic named /chatter. And the rqt_graph seems correct, too. But when I excute rostopic echo chatter (or /chatter), I can not get messages "Helloworld n". When I see rqt_graph, it shows that both android node and rostopic node subscribe to topic /chatter.
So here comes the problem. Why does rostopic echo get nothing but the android node can get messages while they're subscribing to exactly one same topic? I'd appriciate it if anyone can help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197034/android-subscriber-can-get-msg-but-%22rostopic-echo%22-cannot?/) by [SilverBullet](https://answers.ros.org/users/20740/silverbullet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 74 on 2014-11-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gary Servin](https://answers.ros.org/users/10481/gary-servin/) on 2014-11-08**:
What values are you using for ROS_MASTER_URI and ROS_IP (or ROS_HOSTANAME) on Ubuntu? Can you set those env-vars to use the IP of your machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is most likely a network configuration issue. The AVD does not expose a direct network connection to hosts on your LAN, it uses NAT. As the ros master is running on your Android device, you'll need to allow traffic to be routed to the proper IPs through the NAT. See an earlier answer about this: [rosjava nodes isolated and ros tools buggy behavior](http://answers.ros.org/question/195221/rosjava-nodes-isolated-and-ros-tools-buggy-behavior/).

Alternatively, you could try running your master on your host machine, and have your rosjava applications use that as a master. In that case you need to make sure you have working DNS (for both the AVD instance and hosts on your LAN), or just set `ROS_IP` and `ROS_MASTER_URI` appropriately (use plain IPs).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SilverBullet](https://answers.ros.org/users/20740/silverbullet/) on 2014-11-09**:
Thanks a lot. I think it's right that ROS on my ubuntu cannot connect to AVD nodes correctly. It seems that I really should buy a real android phone to continue my study.    orz

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-11-10**:
Well it's probably possible, you'd just have to figure out the correct configuration of the AVD network interfaces. A real device is slightly easier, but I'm not sure it's really needed.